# Checkout does not proceed to step 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

**Magento 2.3.3**

I am trying to finish the checkout an my site, I click the next button, the checkout step on top shows **Review & Payments**, but the content is still the content from step 1 **Shipping**.

I checked the logs and could not find anything suspicious, any idea how to debug this or what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open website in Chrome and use DevTools to check for errors in console related to javascript / network requests.

Perhaps first you will need to spend little time to learn how use this tool for debugging. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript